# Django url include module showing the urls separated by an space

Tags: python, django, module, django-urls

This is my problem now, have a Django project named 'personal' with an urls.py file like this:

```py
# file personal/urls.py

    from django.conf.urls.defaults import *

    ### SAB
    urlpatterns = patterns('',
        (r'^sab/', include('personal.sab.sab_urls')),
    )
    ### STK
    urlpatterns += patterns('',
        (r'^stk/', include('personal.stk.stk_urls')),
    )
    ### TEST
    urlpatterns += patterns('',
        (r'^test_app/', include('personal.test_app.test_app_urls')),
    )
```

And the apps: sab, stk, and test_app with an urls file module like this:

```py
# file personal/test_app/test_app_urls.py

    ### TEST urls.
    from django.conf.urls.defaults import *

    urlpatterns = patterns('personal.test_app',
        (r'^view_1$', 'view_1'),
    )
```

This is what I got in `http://localhost/test_app/` -> [404 error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fInbI.png)

Why some urls modules work fine and other not?
The test_app_urls.py is loaded, but in the screenshot u can see how its look.

Any idea?

Comment: "the screenshot u can"?  What us "u"?

Comment: Can't see what's supposed to be the problem. That there's a 404? You don't have a `test_app/` url specified, so that's fine. That there's nothing under `sab` and `stk`? To say anything about it we'd have to see the problematic urlconfs, not the working one.

Comment: sorry for my english, the problematic is the test_app url module (r'^test_app/', include('personal.test_app.test_app_urls')),

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't appear that you have a url defined for `http://localhost/test_app/` only for `http://localhost/test_app/view_1`

Something along the lines of the following should work (in test_app/urls.py):

```
urlpatterns = patterns('personal.test_app',
    (r'^$', 'test_app_index'),
    (r'^view_1/$', 'view_1'),
)
```